Find all lines on a particular cubic surface
Is there a practical way to find equations of the all 27 lines on the cubic surface $w^3+xz^2+x^2y+y^2z=0$ defined in $\mathbb P^3_{w,x,y,z}$?

Your surface is a cyclic covering of the plane with the branch curve
$$
xz^2 + x^2y + y^2z = 0.
$$
If $P$ is a flex point of the curve and $L$ is its tangent at $P$ then the preimage of $L$ in the surface is the union of three lines. Thus, it is enough to find the 9 flex points, which are the intersection points of the curve with its Hessian.

In M2
R=QQ[w,x,y,z]
I=ideal(w^3+x*z^2+x^2*y+y^2*z)
Fano(1,I)
primaryDecomposition oo -- {ideal(p_2-p_4+p_5,p_0+p_1+p_3,p_1*p_4-p_3*p_4+p_1*p_5+2*p_3*p_5,p_4^3-6*p_4^2*p_5+3*p_4*p_5^2+p_5^3,p_3*p_4^2-7*p_3*p_4*p_5+3*p_1*p_5^2+7*p_3*p_5^2,p_3^2*p_4-p_1^2*p_5-4*p_1*p_3*p_5-3*p_3^2*p_5,p_3^3+p_4^2*p_5,3*p_1*p_3^2+2*p_4^2*p_5-2*p_4*p_5^2-p_5^3,3*p_1^2*p_3+p_4^2*p_5-p_4*p_5^2+p_5^3,p_1^3+p_4*p_5^2-p_5^3),
 -- ideal(p_2*p_3-p_1*p_4+p_0*p_5,p_2^2+p_2*p_4+p_4^2-p_2*p_5+p_4*p_5+p_5^2,p_1*p_2+p_0*p_4-p_1*p_4-p_3*p_4+2*p_0*p_5-p_1*p_5,p_0*p_2+p_0*p_4-2*p_1*p_4+p_0*p_5-p_1*p_5+p_3*p_5,p_0^2-p_0*p_1+p_1^2-p_0*p_3-p_1*p_3+p_3^2,p_3*p_4^2-p_0*p_4*p_5-5*p_1*p_4*p_5+2*p_3*p_4*p_5+3*p_0*p_5^2-p_1*p_5^2+2*p_3*p_5^2,p_2*p_4^2+2*p_4^3-7*p_2*p_4*p_5+5*p_4^2*p_5+p_2*p_5^2+4*p_4*p_5^2+p_5^3,p_1*p_4^2+2*p_0*p_4*p_5+p_3*p_5^2,p_1*p_3*p_4-p_3^2*p_4+p_0*p_1*p_5-2*p_1^2*p_5+4*p_0*p_3*p_5+3*p_1*p_3*p_5-3*p_3^2*p_5,2*p_0*p_3*p_4-5*p_3^2*p_4+p_0*p_1*p_5-5*p_1^2*p_5+15*p_0*p_3*p_5+5*p_1*p_3*p_5-7*p_3^2*p_5,p_3^3+p_4^2*p_5,3*p_1*p_3^2+2*p_2*p_4*p_5-p_5^3,3*p_0*p_3^2+2*p_4^3-7*p_2*p_4*p_5+5*p_4^2*p_5+p_2*p_5^2+3*p_4*p_5^2+p_5^3,3*p_1^2*p_3-p_2*p_4*p_5-p_4^2*p_5+p_2*p_5^2-p_5^3,3*p_0*p_1*p_3-p_4^3+6*p_2*p_4*p_5-3*p_4^2*p_5-3*p_4*p_5^2-p_5^3,p_1^3+p_2*p_5^2,3*p_0*p_1^2-p_4^3+5*p_2*p_4*p_5+p_5^3),
 -- ideal(p_2*p_3-p_1*p_4+p_0*p_5,p_2^2-2*p_2*p_4+p_4^2+2*p_2*p_5-2*p_4*p_5+p_5^2,p_1*p_2*p_5-p_3*p_4*p_5-2*p_0*p_5^2,2*p_0*p_2*p_5-2*p_0*p_4*p_5+p_0*p_5^2-p_1*p_5^2-p_3*p_5^2,p_3*p_4^2+4*p_0*p_4*p_5+2*p_1*p_4*p_5-p_3*p_4*p_5-p_0*p_5^2+2*p_3*p_5^2,p_1*p_4^2+2*p_0*p_4*p_5+p_3*p_5^2,p_0*p_4^2-4*p_0*p_4*p_5+3*p_3*p_4*p_5+2*p_0*p_5^2+p_1*p_5^2-2*p_3*p_5^2,p_0*p_2*p_4-4*p_0*p_4*p_5+p_3*p_4*p_5-2*p_3*p_5^2,2*p_0*p_1*p_4+p_3^2*p_4+p_0^2*p_5+2*p_1*p_3*p_5,p_3^3+p_4^2*p_5,3*p_1*p_3^2+2*p_2*p_4*p_5-p_5^3,3*p_0*p_3^2-p_2*p_4^2-p_4*p_5^2,3*p_1^2*p_3+2*p_2*p_4*p_5-p_4^2*p_5-2*p_2*p_5^2+3*p_4*p_5^2-p_5^3,3*p_0*p_1*p_3-2*p_2*p_4^2+p_4^3+2*p_2*p_4*p_5-p_4^2*p_5+p_2*p_5^2+p_4*p_5^2,3*p_0^2*p_3+p_4^3+2*p_2*p_4*p_5,2*p_0*p_1*p_2+p_1*p_3*p_4-p_1^2*p_5-3*p_0*p_3*p_5,p_0^2*p_2+3*p_1^2*p_4+2*p_0*p_3*p_4-2*p_0*p_1*p_5,p_1^3+p_2*p_5^2,3*p_0*p_1^2-3*p_2*p_4^2+2*p_4^3+8*p_2*p_4*p_5-6*p_4^2*p_5-3*p_2*p_5^2+6*p_4*p_5^2-2*p_5^3,3*p_0^2*p_1+p_2*p_4^2-2*p_2*p_4*p_5+p_4^2*p_5+2*p_2*p_5^2-2*p_4*p_5^2+p_5^3,p_0^3-2*p_2*p_4^2+p_4^3+2*p_2*p_4*p_5-2*p_4^2*p_5+p_4*p_5^2,8*p_4^2*p_5^2+5*p_2*p_5^3-10*p_4*p_5^3+4*p_5^4)}
apply(oo,degree) -- {9, 18, 66}
apply(ooo,dim) -- {1, 1, 0}

Maybe more hands-on $(1:0:-1:-1)$ is a point on the surface and following the algorithm from this pdf for $(0,-1,-1)$ on $1+xz^2+x^2y+y^2z=0$ I get
(271*t^9+324*t^8-1269*t^7-1563*t^6+1242*t^5+2484*t^4+1236*t^3+270*t^2+27*t+1)
(413713*t^18+4924773*t^17+29673945*t^16+107087073*t^15+255022560*t^14+430506576*t^13+539459205*t^12+512321598*t^11+368607591*t^10+198778430*t^9+80573346*t^8+26316414*t^7+8332071*t^6+2832786*t^5+857790*t^4+187602*t^3+26325*t^2+2106*t+73).

Where the degree 9 polynomial has 3 real roots
t = -0.09839412075226706,t = -0.14681132068681, t = -1.952195915931268

whereas the degree 18 poly has no real roots. I could try to go back through the transformations to get the lines explicitly...

In affine coordinates ($u=1$) the equation of the surface is $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x+1=0$. Write the paramatric equation of a generic line in $3$-space $(t, a t + b, c t + d)$, plug into the equation of the cubic and equal all coefficients to $0$ ( $4$ of them). Get a system in $(a,b,c,d)$ that will have $27$ solutions ( so all lines on this cubic are generic and not on the plane at infinity - a simpler case). However, only $3$ of the solutions will be real, and the other $24$ will be complex.  Check out a picture in Desmos  here.
